# How to: Single Repository shared between multiple users in Github

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I am working on a project. In this project multiple developers involved. I have created a repository on github using github for windows and clone this repository. Now, I need to share this repository between these specific developers. So that these specific developers can change/commit any file to this repository. How do I do this?

Comment: Collaborators and Organization is the way to go. But I prefer Organization  which is very flexible.